# Ansible - ios_vlan unable to run any commands that require privilege mode

Tags: ansible

I've been testing ansible for some simple network automation and it seems I'm unable to complete even some simple tasks.  I'm having an issue where any commands that require enable mode are failing.  At the moment it's failing with a command timeout issue.  I've already tried increasing the timeout from 10 to 30 seconds with the same failed result.  Running commands that do not require elevation work properly.

Here's the error from debug logs:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/ansible-connection", line 292, in main
  messages.extended(conn.update_play_context(pc_data))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils/connection.py? line 173, in __rpc__
   raise ConnectionError(to_text(msg, errors='surrogate_then_replace'), code=code)
ConnectionError: command timeout triggered, timeout value is 30 secs.
```

The playbook in question:

```
- name: Test playbook
  hosts: wb
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: fix for prompt issue
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - disable
 - name: Add interface to VLAN
   become: yes
   become_method: enable
   ios_vlan:
      vlan_id: 11
      interfaces:
        - fast5/46
```

I've also tried using the ios_command module and sending the individual commands, but that results in a similar output.  Preference is to use the ios_vlan module.

group varibales:

```
ansible_connection: network_cli
ansible_network_os: ios
ansible_user: myUserName
ansible_ssh_pass: MyPassword
```

I found references to similar issues on git and tried many of the fixes, but nothing I've done so far fixed the issue.

The "fix for prompt issue" task referenced above is because as soon as I log in our prompt ends with a # even though we are not logged into enable mode (not sure if it's something to do with tacacs)... running the "disable" command makes the prompt go back to >, then in the second task going to enable doesn't throw any errors that I can see.

Running against a Cisco Catlyst 4500 running IOS-XE 03.04.05.SG.

Any help would be much appreciated.